# Is it possible to run JavaFX on Ubuntu booting on command line only?

Tags: ubuntu, javafx

I am running my JavaFX GUI application on Ubuntu 18.04 Xfce and it works fine with the X starting. But my goal is to start the jar automatically when the system boots without GUI, because I would like to save some RAM. If I close X and run the jar on command line it shows "Cannot open Display"; do you know if it is possible to do so?